# Nginx one domaine add two project - back-end & front-end

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Example -

- mydomaine.com/back-end/api ---> its back-end
- mydomaine.com ---> its front-end

I don't think many people understand this question. Because I don't understand how things will be. If anyone has trouble understanding my question - comment and tell me I will try to write better

anyone help plz..

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Pretend someone were asking you to help you with the same problem. You'd want them to clearly explain what they are trying to do, what they have tried already, etc. Have a read of the guide to asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then have a go at editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a server block configuration of Nginx, try the following configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomaine.com;

  location /back-end/api {
    # This would be the directory where your app static files are stored at
    root /var/www/html/;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }


  location / {
    proxy_set_header   Host            $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade         $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection      "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy   true;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_pass         http://mydomaine.com;
  }
}
```

Comment: i have two project - (back-end  and front-end) I want my front-end URLs like [mydoamine.com] and back-end URLs like [mydaomine.com/back-end/api]

my back-end is django rest_framwork and front-end  nuxtjs